# Scan software for ubuntu with built-in (GhostScript) compression

Tags: pdf, scanner, compression

**My situation**
I use XSane scanning software to scan documents. I like how it works. Only downside is that the resulting files are large. E.g. an A4-size full-color scan at 300 DPI is a ~10 MB pdf-file.

I have found a method using GhostScript [here](https://tuxdiary.com/2015/04/07/compress-pdf-files-linux/) to compress the pdf-files. They go from ~10 MB to ~200 kb while still perfectly legible. So the results are awesome, but it is a second manual step I have to perform in the terminal.

**My question**
Is there also scanning software that has built-in compression possibilities similar to these of GhostScript? Then I would have a one-step perfect solution.

Thanks for any help you can give!